# What is the grammatical analysis of the sentence 「君を笑いに来た」?

Tags: grammar

In English, the popular translation of 「君を笑いに来た」 is "I came to laugh at you," but ever since I heard the original in Japanese, I was curious as to what is going on in the sentence from the grammatical perspective (in particular, the 「笑いに来た」 part). Does anyone know?

Comment: We discussed this construction a bit in chat today, starting around [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19917195#19917195).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... are you asking how to grammatically break down 「君を笑いに来た」?

Comment: My particular focus is on 笑いに来た. I've never seen that explained before, and I'm curious on how that works, grammatically

Comment: OK. I tried to clarify the English, let me know if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your Sentence

This is how it breaks down:

```
[君を　　　　笑い　　　]に　　　 来た  
[kimi=wo     waraw-i   ]=ni      ki-ta  
[you=PATIENT laugh-CONT]=PURPOSE come-PAST
"I came to laugh at you"
```

That is:

- the inner clause is 「君を笑う」 "laugh at you",
- that inner clause gets inflected to the 連用形{れんようけい}: 「君を笑い」,
- then it gets added as an argument to 「来た」 via the `PURPOSE` 「〜に」

---

## The `PURPOSE` 「に」

I call this 「に」 the `PURPOSE` 「に」 in my gloss above.

1. **Most verbs do not take a `PURPOSE` 「に」 argument**: usually, if you want to specify the purpose you need to do something more complex like 「ために〜」.

   **The verbs that do allow for this `PURPOSE` 「に」 are movement verbs (移動動詞).**

   In *A Reference Grammar of Japanese*, Samuel Martin gives examples of verbs that take the `PURPOSE` 「に」:

   > 行く・来る・かえる・戻る・出る・出向く・出かける・赴く・寄る・入る・歩く・上る・押し寄せる・向かう・集まる・群がる・立つ・逃げる・顔を出す・かかる

   (Pulled out of examples on Martin 1975, pp. 405-406.)

   This is far from a conclusive list though.
2. On the **inner verb** (「笑う」, in your case), there's a semantic constraint. Basically, the inner verb needs to be something a human willfully does. Examples of inner verbs that don't work are 「開く」 (not something a human does) and 「乗り過ごす」 (not something you willfully do).

Comment: This is a short summary, with details mainly from *A Reference Grammar of Japanese*. (Thanks to snailboat for finding the relevant pages.) I think figuring out *exactly* what verbs accept the `PURPOSE` 「に」 is an interesting thing, and is what I was trying to do in the chat log linked in the question comments. Anyways, hopefully this answers your question, if not, feel free to ask for clarification.